# as3 How to properly fill object with data from XML

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

I would like to fill an object with my xml data.
It sounds easy but the thing is, the object will be nested not once but twice.
The XML file looks like this:

```
<antwoordenlijst>
        <antwoorden id="1">
            <antwoord keuze="a" value="0" volgnr="1">Ja, alles beter dan dat honden weer in Nederland</antwoord>
            <antwoord keuze="b" value="0" volgnr="1">Gaat wel</antwoord>
            <antwoord keuze="c" value="0" volgnr="1">Nee, ik heb toch liever het weer in Nederland</antwoord>
        </antwoorden>
        <antwoorden id="2">
            <antwoord keuze="a" value="10" volgnr="2">Volgens mij maakt de kleur voor jouw niet veel uit, alles staat je goed</antwoord>
            <antwoord keuze="b" value="0" volgnr="2">Ik geef je vrouw gelijk</antwoord>
            <antwoord keuze="c" value="-30" volgnr="2">Het staat je allebei niet.</antwoord>
        </antwoorden>
```

etc...

What i tried was this:

```
private function antwoordenGeladen(e:Event):void
    {
        var antwoordenOverzichtIndex = 0;
        deXmlData = new XML(deLader.data);
        for (var i:Number=0; i<26; i++) 
        {
            var xmlAntwoorden:XMLList = deXmlData.antwoordenlijst;
            var antw:Object = new Object();
            for (var s:Number=0; s<3; s++)
            {
                antw["Keuze"] = xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s).@keuze;
                antw["Value"] = xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s).@value;
                antw["Volgnr"] = xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s).@volgnr;
                antw["Vraag"] = xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s);
                antw["Id"] = xmlAntwoorden.child(i).@id;
                antwoordenLijst[antwoordenOverzichtIndex] = antw;
                antwoordenOverzichtIndex++;
            }
            antwoordenOverzicht[i] = antwoordenLijst;

        }

    }
```

But for some reason it will overwrite the values at antwoordenOverzicht[i]

Tho if i check with the debugger the variable i will go up each time its out of the loop so i`m quite confused.

If anyone sees a better method of doing this or just knows the answer i would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do what you're trying to do a bit more succinctly like this (untested):

```
private function antwoordenGeladen(e:Event):void
{
    deXmlData = new XML(deLader.data);

    for (var i:Number=0; i<26; i++) 
    {
        var xmlAntwoorden:XMLList = deXmlData.antwoordenlijst;
        var antwoordenLijst = [];

        for (var s:Number=0; s<3; s++)
        {
            antwoordenLijst.push({
                keuze: xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s).@keuze,
                value: xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s).@value,
                volgnr: xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s).@volgnr,
                vraag: xmlAntwoorden.child(i).child(s),
                id: xmlAntwoorden.child(i).@id
            });
        }
        antwoordenOverzicht.push(antwoordenLijst);
    }
}
```